# UML Class Diagram. Как отобразить связь между Inner и Outer классами?

Tags: uml, диаграммы, visio

Внутри одного класса есть другой, вложенный member class.
Что использовать в этом случае:

**Composition** (закрашенный ромб) или **Containment** (кружок с плюсом) ?

Генераторы UML из кода используют Containment, а учитель использует Композицию с уточняющим словом "Contain".

И почему нотацию Containment нельзя использовать в Visio 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [английской Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Containment_(computer_programming)):

> Containment is a subtype of composition that is used to store several instances of the composited data type is referred to as containment. Examples of such containers are arrays, associative arrays, binary trees, and linked lists.
>
> In UML, containment is depicted with a multiplicity of 1 or 0..n (depending on the issue of ownership), indicating that the data type is composed of an unknown number of instances of the composited data type.

Если по-русски:

> Содержание (**Containment**) – это подвид композиции (**Composition**), который используется для хранения множества экземпляров хранимых данных. Примерами могут быть массивы, связанные списки, словари.
>
> В UML содержание (**Containment**) показывается связью с множественностью 1 или 0..n (в зависимости от частного случая), показывая, что один тип данных хранится в другом с заранее неизвестным числовом экземпляров.

То есть, содержанием называют композицию, где число зависимых экземпляров может быть неопределённо большим.

В самой [спецификации UML](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams) не выделяют Containment отдельно от Composition, вероятно, упомянутая нотация не является официальной. Однако диаграммы служат для упрощения понимания сути программы, поэтому некоторые детали могут варьироваться в разумных пределах, и оба описанные автором вопроса варианта могут быть уместны.

Comment: Одна оговорка, сам сайт uml-diagrams.org не является спецификацией, хотя сам сайт очень хороший и ИМХО раскрывает дух оной...

Comment: Группа разработчиков спецификаций UML https://www.omg.org
Object Management Group. 
Они обучают и выдают сертификаты по UML различных версий.